# ASP.NET Ajax client framework failed to load

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

We developed an web application using visual studio 2008. In my development PC, the application is working fine. In production server I am getting the following exception "ASP.NET AJAX CLIENT FRAMEWORK FAILED TO LOAD". What should I do to make it work?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with making sure all of the appropriate service packs are applied and that the 3.5 framework is actually installed on the box.

Also, make sure any assembly you reference that isn't part of your deployment is gac'd on the machine.  Check version numbers.

All else being equal, I'd guess the server is just way out of date on it's updates.